# Material Design SearchView has no method "setOnQueryTextListener"

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, searchbar

I am struggling to implement material components search in my android app following [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Search.md) tutorial

I built a basic app with viewbinding, added `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'` created a fragment with the default xml code given in that description, run the app, everything looks fine, i see a searchbar that i can tap to open searchView and enter a query, so far so good.

But: I am not able to implement the method to get the query and start the search, because when i try to do something like `binding.searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(...)` i get an error saying that method does not exist.

What am i doing wrong or miss?

Comment: It's not available on material design [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/search/SearchView), only on android jetpack appcompat [SearchView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SearchView).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this workaround: `searchView` has a child `editText` that you can add a text change listener to. Don't know why this is not documented in the example.

```
binding.searchView.editText.addTextChangedListener { editable ->
    /* do magic */
}
```